# How to tell if rake db:migrate and rake db:seed were successful

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, schema, seed, dbmigrate

Ruby rake db:seed aborting due to ** Execute db:abort_if_pending_migrations, but I think all the migrations were successful.

Here's the last portion of the output when I run rake db:migrate --trace

```
    ** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
    ** Execute db:load_config
    ** Execute db:migrate
    ** Invoke db:_dump (first_time)
    ** Execute db:_dump
    ** Invoke db:schema:dump (first_time)
    ** Invoke environment 
    ** Invoke db:load_config 
    ** Execute db:schema:dump
```

I assume that mean it was successful (I didn't see any aborts)?

Then when I run rake db:seed --trace I get (in summary):

```
    ** Invoke db:seed (first_time)
    ** Execute db:seed
    ** Invoke db:abort_if_pending_migrations (first_time)
    ** Invoke environment (first_time)
    ** Execute environment
    loading plugins
```

(the plugins load with no errors) then:

```
    ** Execute db:abort_if_pending_migrations
```

does this mean the  migration and the seed worked properly or not? 
Thank you for your time & input!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it didn't abort, it succeeded.  Take a [look at the code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/bbaad89ba892b76e581a122893e628dbd306ac7e/activerecord/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake):

```
# desc "Raises an error if there are pending migrations"
task :abort_if_pending_migrations => :environment do
  pending_migrations = ActiveRecord::Migrator.open(ActiveRecord::Migrator.migrations_paths).pending_migrations

  if pending_migrations.any?
    puts "You have #{pending_migrations.size} pending #{pending_migrations.size > 1 ? 'migrations:' : 'migration:'}"
    pending_migrations.each do |pending_migration|
      puts '  %4d %s' % [pending_migration.version, pending_migration.name]
    end
    abort %{Run `rake db:migrate` to update your database then try again.}
  end
end
```

It literally does nothing if there aren't any pending migrations.